# IEDriver Server 4.0.0.0 doesn't provide any response when running using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I recently upgraded the IE Driver server to version 4.0.0.0 32- bit. When I run my test case it launches the browser but never shows any error or responds.

Selenium Version - 3.141.59 IE Version:

[image]

IE Webbrowser after launching:

[image]

Below Capabilities added:

[image]

NOTE: If I use IEDriver -3.150.1.0 it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

When using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) and [iedriverserver](/questions/tagged/iedriverserver) it is recommended to use the latest version of the ***major*** releases. As an example,

- Incase you are using *Selenium Version - 3.141.59* ideally you should be using [iedriverserver v3.150.2.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/f95054319b6d8cb56b0d5202cffa9d0a9845ed22/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG#L20)
- Incase you are using *Selenium Version - 4.0.0* ideally you should be using [iedriverserver v4.0.0.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/f95054319b6d8cb56b0d5202cffa9d0a9845ed22/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG#L12)